# Help mac share files with XP machine on different subnets

Tags: mac, network, smb, windows, file-sharing

I have a personal Macbook running Lion (10.7.1) and a Company issued laptop running XP at work.

I want to access the files on the mac from XP on a regular basis. Right now using "sneaker net", i.e. swapping USB stick – but keeping files in sync is a challenge/worry.

The machines are on different networks (subnets) – the XP machine on the 'corporate' locked down network, and the mac on a slightly looser managed wireless 'guest' network. Changing settings on either network is not possible.

The corporate network blocks file sharing services like dropbox.

Any clever ideas on how I can share files across these two machines (which are literally 6 inches apart!)?

I tried using mac SMB file sharing, but crossing subnets seems like a no-go. I do have personal hosted web space available, but setting up syncing (maybe Goodsync) with both machines and encrypting files on the server would be a big hassle.

So, is there some relatively easy way to do this I'm missing, or have I been completely stymied by my corporate IT overlords?

Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Most people use ssh tunnels as port 80 is usually open. There's a good question [here about mac software to set up a tunnel](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16976/what-is-a-good-gui-for-ssh-tunneling-in-mac-osx-snow-leopard-lion). Also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osx+ssh+tunnel?sort=votes&pagesize=15

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [USBG-MAC-PC](http://www.usbgear.com/USBG-MAC-PC.html) cable which does exactly what you want. It doesn't require installation of any drivers or any intervention of your company admins.

Here some guy shows how it works: http://www.usbgear.com/link/index.html .
Note, that he shows different cable model, the one that you need is on the bottom of the page.